# Replay Edge animation on ui-view load in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, animation, adobe-edge

I'm building a project with angularJS. I use ui-router for views, and nested views.
So I have a index.html with just the header, the footer and a "general" ui-view where I load asychronously the Home-view, Contacts-view, About-view, etc.

On the "home" page and on the "about" page there are two different Adobe Edge animations.
They work like charm when I load them for the first time, but when I navigate through the website  and then I come back to the home or the about page nothing appears.

I've tried loading the edge scripts in different ways

- in the index.html head with the script tags
- in a angular directive
- in the controller
- during the routing processes via the resolve option of ui-router

None of this strategies fixed the problem. The animations still play just once.

Finally I decided diving in the js code crafted automatically by Adobe Edge (I'm not a designer, I have no idea on how to create animation with Edge).

I found that Edge create an AdobeEdge object and bind it to the window... then call the animation throught an event handler in a jQuery anonymous function

```
(function($, Edge, compId){
   ....

   $(window).ready(function() {
        Edge.launchComposition(compId);
   });

})(jQuery, AdobeEdge, "EDGE-123456");
```

On the official Adobe documentation (really bad!) there are some methods to call on the AdobeEdge object...

I tryied to insert in the home-controller the following line

```
$window.AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-123456").getStage().play();
```

but doesn't work.

After a wasted whole day I'm frustrated, I hate who ho conceived Adobe Edge scripting and overall I need an help to fix it the right way (beofore implementing horrible workaround).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using `playAll()`. I imagine this plays all the Symbol timelines at once (it's difficult to know for sure since the documentation is so vague), but I've found it works for my purposes.

`$window.AdobeEdge.getComposition("EDGE-123456").getStage().playAll();`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Deosn't work. It seems I can't even call the play method...angular throws undefined error